# what device name should I have to give in snd_pcm_open other than "default"

Tags: c, alsa

I want to record sound from 2 devices simultaneously:

- internal mic
- external usb webcam mic

Using `pulseaudio` sound controller, I set either of these devices as default and could record sound with `snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)`.

But now I want to record sound from both devices simultaneously, so i have to opt for naming scheme mentioned [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html#pcm_dev_names_hw). However I have no success with couple of them.

I thought [this](https://superuser.com/questions/53957/what-do-alsa-devices-like-hw0-0-mean-how-do-i-figure-out-which-to-use#answer-53977) would solve my problem, but `front:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0` didn't help as the name of device.

I get these errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
```

`arecord -l` gives me:

```
# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog [ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U0x46d0x825 [USB Device 0x46d:0x825], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and `# arecord -L` gives:

```
# arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=U0x46d0x825
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=U0x46d0x825
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0
    USB Device 0x46d:0x825, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

So what are the correct names I should give in to the above devices to record them simultaneously as per the ALSA specification?

I **don't** want to use `pulseaudio` API.

Comment: See the [multi plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_multi). But this will not work for long if the devices' clocks are not synchronized.

Comment: @CL. I don't want to mix the streams. I just want to capture the two inputs simultaneously in to separate period buffers.

Comment: Try `default:0` and `default:1`.

Comment: got following errors with both default:0 and default:1 `ALSA lib conf.c:4694:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters 1
      ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default:1`

Comment: Apparently, PA overrides the default device. Try `plughw:0` and `plughw:1`.

Comment: @CL. It worked! Now how can i find which device is what? When I use 2 webcams which I will hot plug, how to find the mapped PA device name of a mic?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that `front:`, from [the other question](https://superuser.com/questions/53957/what-do-alsa-devices-like-hw0-0-mean-how-do-i-figure-out-which-to-use), would not have worked since `front:` refers to a set of speakers, rather than a microphone or recording device. You could use the `hw:CARD=X,Y` format, but you'll get a little bit more flexibility if you use, as @CL suggests, the `plughw:CARD=X,Y`. Plughw can automatically take care of resampling or value conversion versus `hw:CARD=X,Y`.

Based on your output from `arecord -l` and `arecord -L`:

- Internal mic should be: `plughw:DEV=0,CARD=PCH`, or just `plughw:PCH,0`
- USB Webcam should be: `plughw:DEV=0,CARD=U0x46d0x825` or just `plughw:U0x46d0x825,0`

Answer (score 1):

If you run both Pulseaudio and ALSA, what happens is that Pulseaudio provdes a compatibility layer as default, using a configuration similar to

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

That means if you `snd_pcm_open` the `default` device, you talk to Pulseaudio, which then routes you according to the preference stored for the application name.

Pulseaudio also opens ALSA devices when it uses them. ALSA `hw` devices can only be opened once, so as soon as Pulseaudio has opened them, you'll get a "busy" error if you try to access them via the ALSA API. That also applies to plugins provided automatically, like `front`, `plughw` etc. You got away using `plughw` because Pulseaudio hadn't already opened them when you tried, this won't work in general.

The options you have are:

(1) Stop Pulseaudio completely, then you can open ALSA devices with `snd_pcm_open` in whatever way you like, using `CARD` etc. to identify the device.

(2) Use the Pulseaudio API.

(3) Make a combined device for your two soundcards, either in ALSA or in Pulseaudio, and manually set this as the preferred sink for your application, then use the Pulseaudio compatibility layer via `default`.

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
$ cat /proc/asound/devices
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  5: [ 0- 3]: hardware dependent
  6: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  7: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer
```

use the first audio device that has a device number other than zero